# What is the difference between a list and a string in Python?

Tags: python, list

This is my code.

```
data2 = []
f = open("test_file.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8")
while True:
data = f.readline()
if len(data) >= 150:
    data = data.replace(". ", ".")
    data = data.replace(".", ".\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n”\n", ".”\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n’\n", ".’\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n」\n", ".」\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n』\n", ".』\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n〉\n", ".〉\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n]\n", ".]\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n}\n", ".}\n")
    data = data.replace(".\n)\n", ".)\n")
if not data:
    break
data2.append(data + "\n")

f.close()
```

The size of the test_file is approximately 10 mb.

In this code, data2 = [] and using "append" function.
The time required is 0.1 seconds.

But, when data2 = "" and using data2 = data2 + data, it needs 40 seconds.

It wasn't like this when I was using Python 3.9, but this has been happening since the 3.11 upgrade.
May I know why?

Comment: Creating a long string from concatenation should be slower than appending values to a list. String concatenation involves creating a new string. List appending only requires adding a reference to the string as an item in the list. So, not really a surprise - you would have to show your benchmarks if your claim is that this is a problem with 3.11 vs 3.9. As far as the difference between a list and a string - well, there's many. Lists can contain strings, for instance, but strings cannot contain lists.

Comment: _It wasn't like this when I was using Python 3.9_ Press X for doubt.

Comment: Well, on my machine, there is no timing difference between python 3.8 and python 3.11. I don't have python 3.9 installed, and I won't install it just to verify the very unlikely hypothesis that implementation was changed twice, back and forth, between 3.8 and 3.11. But if you really want to make a reproducible experiment to ask your question, it is very easy to install python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the underlying nature of the data types and the manner in which they are implemented, whereas both the string and list types are sequential in nature the matter in which they grow in size differs.

For starters lists in general are composed of a sequence of cells, each of which containing the value at the corresponding location within the sequence plus, depending on the nature of the list i.e. singly or doubly linked, one or two pointers which point towards the next and previous cells. Growing a list implies allocating one cell an inserting it at the desired location, if the location isn't trivial i.e. the beginning or end of the list the operation will take longer since an auxiliary pointer will be required so as to properly insert the cell.

When it comes to strings, things are a tad different, because even though you process a string most often than not sequentially, it's underlying memory representation is a contiguous block of memory of fixed sized, similar to that of an array in low-level languages such as C for which the length of the block is known prior to creation of it (therefore enabling fast subscripting). In order to grow such a block in size you will have to allocate a new address in memory which is big enough to hold both the current data and the new one, which is exactly what Python does and most languages do. Hence, when you are concatenating two strings together, the cost of the operation is bigger than say pushing an element to the front of a list, since the resulting string will undergo a series of steps prior to it being available; those steps being:

1. A new memory zone is reserved which has the size equal to the sum of the lengths of the two strings, in your case data2 and data plus one (for the null terminator);
2. the contents of the first string is copied into the new memory block, then the contents of the second are copied.

Now, since you are constantly increasing the size of data2 in your program, this operation will but become more and more arduous and costly thus resulting in quite lengthy programs, duration wise.

Regarding the speed difference, I am not aware of any changes to the string type in Python, maybe in previous versions they might have used a form of dynamic array for growing strings hence making them slightly faster, though the problem with this approach is that more often than not you end reserving way more memory than you end up using, hence depleting your resources for naught.